# Bamboo Script Task using inline bat commands failing

Tags: jmeter, bamboo

Im new to Bamboo and just trying to run this two lines of code in the script task.

```
cd C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\
jmeter-n.cmd Test.jmx​
```

It is failing and it is showing this message on the logs.
Failing task since return code of [c:\Program Files\Bamboo\temp\TEST-16-ScriptBuildTask-4637676047487491491.bat] was -1 while expected 0

Answer (score 0):

1. Is path to JMeter correct?
2. Does Test.jmx script live in JMeter's bin directory
3. Do you have "java.exe" in your PATH environment variable? [Does Bamboo pick it up](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMKB/Bamboo+does+not+pick+up+the+Path+environment+variable+correctly)?
4. Can you look into "C:\apache-jmeter-2.11\bin\Test.log" file to see whether they are errors there. If there is no such a file one of points 1-3 isn't met.
5. Are you aware of [Bamboo JMeter Plugin](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bamboo-jmeter-plugin)?

By the way, Bamboo is capable of executing [Ant](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Ant) or [Maven](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Maven) tasks and JMeter test can be kicked off using these build systems as well.

References:

- [Automated Performance Testing using Maven and JMeter](http://www.slideshare.net/PerconaPerformance/automated-performance-testing-with-j-meter-and-maven)
- [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterMavenPlugin)
- [5 Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](http://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)